# Close Google Chrome tab remotely from another device

Tags: google-chrome, tabs

I often forget a music/video stream open in a Chrome tab on another device. Chrome's device listing at chrome://history/syncedTabs lets me reopen the tab on the current device. However, this opens a duplicate of the tab and leaves the remote tab open. I'm looking for a Chrome feature or extension that would let me close the original tab remotely. Would be nice if the extension would work on both Mac and Windows. The extension can use Internet for communication.

Comment: Please provide details of 'devices' & method of access.

Comment: The devices are listed under chrome://history/syncedTabs

Comment: …which we can't see from here...

Comment: This question should include more details and clarify the problem.

Comment: I added Mac/Windows and Internet to the problem description